# C++ Multithreading Callback Timer Function Thread Safety

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, thread-safety, threadpool

Suppose I have implemented a callback timer class. The class takes the following arguments:

- a timeout interval
- a function to run

At the end of each timeout period the class spawns a thread and passes it the function to run. The function is not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Further suppose that the timeout interval is shorter than the time it takes the function to finish executing. In this case I would want the "request" to run the callback function to be "queued" so that it runs **after** the first invocation completes. I do not want two threads to be executing that same function concurrently.

How could I do this using std C++11 supported concurrency libraries?

...Another caveat, what if two timer instantiations are passed the same function?

Example callback:

```
void myCallback() {
   // Do something
   std::cout << "Callback function executed.\n";
   std::stringstream ss;

   int seconds = 5;
   for (int i = seconds; i > 0; i--)
   {
      ss << "Processing data on thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ". Ending in " << i << " seconds\n";
      std::cout << ss.str();
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

      ss.str(std::string());
   }
   ss << "Thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Finished!\n";
   std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

If I created multiple timer objects on the main thread, and passed the same callback function to each, would I be able to coordinate access to the function *across* instances?

Comment: Generally you should not rely on functions having identities in C++.  Do you really want that to be the case?  I strongly suggest no.  Second, if you want to different instances of a timer to behave together, you probably want one object behind those two timers (a scheduler) that the two of them connect to.  Ideally concurrent code passes as much information along side the task as possible and the task operates on the passed on information, then returns results via a thread safe mechanism...

Comment: Second, spawning a thread per task is a bad plan.  You want a pool of threads and want to reuse threads if possible.  If the tasks are CPU-bound, you want to limit how many tasks run at once.  Third, it is completely unclear what it means for the same task to be run every 5 ms and every 2 ms.  Does this run at 0 ms 2 ms 4 ms 5 ms 6 ms 8 ms 10 ms twice 12 ms 14 ms 15 ms ?  If it takes 3 ms to run, does it just queue up and run immediately when it finishes the last time?

Comment: You are getting an AI-generated answer probably because people who know how to solve your problem are looking at your problem description and saying "the result of your specs will be horrible".  I suspect you are thinking of "I don't want to worry about concurrency", and unfortunetally concurrency doesn't let you not worry about it.  If you attempt to not worry about concurrency, you'll get a framework that hides concurrency problems from you, not a framework that solves concurrency problems.